# Custom 12.10 Panel

Tags: unity, 12.10, panel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I customize the Unity top panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88467/how-can-i-customize-the-unity-top-panel)

I've done quite a bit of research on this and don't believe it's possible but I figured I'd throw the question out there anyway and see what kind of answers I get.

I'm looking for a way to customize the panel in Ubuntu 12.10.  I believe this is the Unity panel (feel free to correct me if I'm wrong... I'm fairly new to Linux and new to Ubuntu).  I am specifically looking to center the time on the panel.  I would like to explore other customization if possible but I figured I'd start with something simple.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Nope not possible with Unity. http://askubuntu.com/questions/88467/how-can-i-customize-the-unity-top-panel and here is a long list with possible alterations to Unity: http://askubuntu.com/questions/29553/how-can-i-configure-unity None have something about the panel.

Comment: Could you expand on "I've done quite a bit of research" in the question itself?

Comment: @vasa1, "research" is searching on this and other forums via Google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will accept the answer Jo-Erlend Schinstad gave on this post: [How can I customize the Unity top panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88467/how-can-i-customize-the-unity-top-panel)

Turns out, the Unity panel is quite limited in what can be placed there and with good reason.  Anyway, I will most likely install tint2 or another panel in addition to the Unity panel and see how it goes... may just stick with the Unity panel by itself if it's too much trouble to deal with two.

Thanks all!